# C++ program compiles on two different machines. Shared library works properly on one. On the other, class-methods return NULL

Tags: c++, c, linux, g++, openbabel

I'm trying to write some programs using the openbabel libraries, one of which is a simple program to extract data from an sdf file. But one of the functions I have FormatFromExt is not working. The function call returns NULL no matter what input parameters I pass it.

```
OpenBabel::OBFormat *inputFormat = conv.FormatFromExt(argv[1]);
// This method fails, returns NULL ^^
if (!inputFormat || !conv.SetInFormat(inputFormat)) {
  char buf[256];
  sprintf(buf, "Could not find input format for file: %s", inputFormat);
  cerr << buf << endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

Other methods for this class, OBConversion, also return NULL such as `SetInfFormat`, `FindFormat` and `Read`.

I've verified that argv[1] indeed holds the input file's path and that the file has a valid extension for the openbabel libraries. I'm also including all necessary header files. On one machine, this code works perfectly. On the other the methods fail. The program compiles perfectly on both. What would cause something like this to happen?

The openbabel libraries I'm using are shared object files.

Comment: Run with strace to see if that gives you any clues. Use -o to send the output to a file. Compare the two traces.

Comment: Blah, sadly this a research project and I don't have permissions to install straces at the moment on one machine. Will definitely come back to this later

Comment: I've gotten strace to work, The file is huge though and I don't really understand the commands that it lists as different. If anyone is feeling determined the diff of the two files can be found [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!fckTFK7K!TkLWrGyxeecHCRce4IjYsVVjUgI3eA35V3ovJcIUzq8)

Comment: Also, it appears that these are from two different executables, mol and sdfconv?

Comment: sorry, the output name of the program on one machine is just different from the name of the other, same source code for both programs though. I will go ahead and make the makefiles identitical so that it doesn't needlessly complicate the diff file. One second

Comment: argv[1] contains the name of the input file to read, it should be files/Compound_014725001_014750000.sdf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51721/discussion-between-user3521733-and-kjh)

Comment: @kjh: Like I commented in the now closed almost exact duplicate of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379129/c-is-there-a-more-thoroughly-documented-bioinformatics-library-than-openbabel) openbabel is Open Source and you can look into the source code of e.g. `FormatFromExt` to see what it expects. Did you at least try that? If you have a debug build stepping through the function will also tell you where things go wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have. I've examined strace files of both builds and I don't see any obvious difference and myself along with the other students I'm working with aren't necessarily able to read these files properly. That is why I'm posting here. Reading through the source files is not helping us at all. This is a very large library and given the number of places our issue is occurring it is not at all obvious to us which files we should be looking through

Comment: There are many differences in diff of the two strace files, most of which show a set of commands on the local machine continuing to execute where the remote machine breaks from it's current point and moves on to a different spot in the program. I don't know how to read this file. I understand some of the system calls but I also don't have the time at the moment to go digging through the entire openbabel library and repeatedly send requests to our server admin to recompile the libraries every time I make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this appears to be a misconfiguration. Basically, it seems to be looking for .so files, and doesn't find any on the remote machine.

So let's look at the two traces, starting from where they diverge. It's not hard to find, since it's basically at the end of the failed trace. First, let's look at the one that works:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
brk(0x1199000)                          = 0x1199000
getdents(5, /* 112 entries */, 32768)   = 4200
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
futex(0x7f7fbacf90b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2/castepformat.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
read(5, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340.\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=521866, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2126352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0) = 0x7f7fba3db000
mprotect(0x7f7fba3e2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fba5e1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x6000) = 0x7f7fba5e1000
close(5)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fba5e1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2/xedformat.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
read(5, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260'\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=432606, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2118032, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0) = 0x7f7fba1d5000
mprotect(0x7f7fba1da000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fba3d9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x4000) = 0x7f7fba3d9000
close(5)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fba3d9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2/PQSformat.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
```

It opens the directory `/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2`, then reads all the entries in it. There are 4200 bytes worth of entries. It then sequentially loads in a bunch of .so files (shared libraries). These are presumably what it found in `/usr/local/lib/openbabel/2.3.2`.

Okay, now lets look at the one that failed:

```
open("/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib/openbabel", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
brk(0x1dd6000)                          = 0x1dd6000
getdents(5, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
brk(0x1dce000)                          = 0x1dce000
close(5)                                = 0
write(2, "Could not find input format for "..., 76Could not find input format for file: files/Compound_014725001_014750000.sdf) = 76
```

It opens instead `/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib/openbabel`. It then reads only 80 bytes worth of entries, presumably because that directory is empty or near empty. It then immediately prints the error message.

So appears that the configuration is pointing to the wrong directory, or that the directory never got populated with all the .so files. Note that it found `Compound_014725001_014750000.sdf` fine in both cases. If you look a few lines above from where I start to quote, you can see the syscalls for that open.

Comment: This was it! BABEL_LIBDIR needed to be set to the proper directory, in this case `/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib/openbabel/2.3.2` it then found the rest of the libraries and the program compiled fine. Thank you very much.